# Asp.net, visual Basic, If-Site navigation

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, button, radio-button

I have an short question.

It is about something like a true/false quiz. 
So I have two Radio Buttons, and if another normal Button is clicked, the website navigates to site A, when radiobutton1 is chosen, and to site B, when radiobutton2 is chosen.

ASPX

```
<p>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" TabIndex="1" Text="Wahr" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" TabIndex="2" Text="Falsch" />
</p>   
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BorderColor="#FF9966" Text="Auswertung" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>  
</p>
```

VB

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If RadioButton1.Checked Then
          <%Response.Redirect()%>

        End If
```

So Visual Studio says me that the part `<% Response.Redirect("/Frage1Richtig")%>` is an Syntax Error. 
And this is my Problem that I have no idea how I can say the button that if the button is clicked it has to navigate to one website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your second part is your code behind (or inline code in your page)
Get rid of the <% and > and just use Response.Redirect("Your url")

So

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   If RadioButton1.Checked Then
      Response.Redirect("Your url")
   End If
..
..
..
```